# SPI problem with Bitcraze PMW3901 sensors and Arduino NANO

Tags: sensors, arduino-nano, spi

I am currently trying to connect four Bitcraze PMW3901 sensors to an Arduino NANO, but I seem to have issues with the SPI. When I connect two sensors using the code below, it works perfectly: I am able to retrieve the X and Y data from the serial port for both sensors.

```
include "Bitcraze_PMW3901.h"

 Bitcraze_PMW3901 flow(10);
 Bitcraze_PMW3901 flow2(9);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  if (!flow.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Initialization of the flow sensor 1 failed");
    while(1) { }
  }

  if (!flow2.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Initialization of the flow sensor 2 failed");
    while(1) { }
  }

}

int i =0;
int16_t deltaX,deltaY;
int16_t deltaX2,deltaY2;

void loop() {
  if ((i % 2) == 0) {
    digitalWrite(10, LOW); // sets the digital pin 10 on
    flow.readMotionCount(&deltaX, &deltaY);
    digitalWrite(10, HIGH);  // sets the digital pin 9 off
  }

  if ((i % 2) == 1) {
    digitalWrite(9, LOW); // sets the digital pin 10 on
    flow2.readMotionCount(&deltaX2, &deltaY2);
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);  // sets the digital pin 9 off
  }

    i = i + 1;
    Serial.print("X1:");
    Serial.print(deltaX);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("Y1:");
    Serial.print(deltaY);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("X2: ");
    Serial.print(deltaX2);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("Y2:");
    Serial.print(deltaY2);
    Serial.print("\n");

}
```

However, when I try to add a third Bitcraze PMW3901 sensor I cannot seem to be able to initilize it. Still, I declare a separete SS as

> Bitcraze_PMW3901 flow3(6);

and add the initialization code in the setup() function as follows

> if (!flow3.begin()) {
> Serial.println("Initialization of the flow sensor 3 failed");
> while(1) { }
> }

What I get is the sentence "Initialization of the flow sensor 3 failed" or "Initialization of the flow sensor 1 failed" (it depends and I don't really understand why, since the code is always the same) printed on the serial port window.

I have already checked my sensors: they all work separetely and two-by-two. Do you have any suggestions? I hope I have managed to explain the problem clearly, otherwise please let me know if I can add or specify something more. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: powering issue? how do you power the sensors?

Comment: Do your sensors incorporate a tri-state buffer on the MISO line for each device?

Comment: Hi Juraj! I power the sensors directly through the Arduino Nano. I have already tried to use an external battery, but the result didn't change so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Hi sempaiscuba! I actually don't know and I can't seem to find this information on the sensors' datasheet. Could you please explain what would be the problem or the advantage of that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most SPI chips will be at tri-state on their MISO pin when their chip select signal is HIGH. Tri-stage means that it is neither HIGH nor LOW (i.e. floated) and effectively disconnect. However, it is not always the case. A SPI device without tri-state MISO could caused potential problem on a SPI bus where multiple SPI devices are connected. If the MISO is unable to be at tri-state, it will be either HIGH or LOW, this will affect other devices connected on the same bus in receiving data. see [this](https://www.pjrc.com/better-spi-bus-design-in-3-steps/) for more explanation and solution.

Comment: It seems that the [library](https://github.com/bitcraze/Bitcraze_PMW3901/blob/master/src/Bitcraze_PMW3901.cpp#L35) is set to running the SPI at 4MHz, this might be a problem when running with multiple slaves, you might want to try to change the library manually to say 1MHz and see if it works?

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue with the pmw3901 sensors when connected to teensy 4.0
@wolly94 were you able to solve your problem? If yes, please could you mention the changes you made?